# CMD search results send to console

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to ask if anyone has an idea how to send search result to console in single command line but with some specific code before and after the search results output

I need to run program Xconverter that is made to be operated by console, and has parameters:

```
-s               :silent mode (only mode suported yet)
-i [files]       : list location of the files in quotes: {-i "a.txt" "b.txt"..} 
-t [tool file]   : tool file location
-m 5             : conversion style
```

syntax accepted for example (single command for XConverter):

```
"C:\XConverter.exe" -s -i "C:\a.pgm" "C:\abc\b.pgm" -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5
```

but I need about 500 -i [files] to list
so i created search that fill look for those `.pgm` in tree mode where .bat is located and adds search result (file locations) one after other

my code is working but the only way i made it to work is that i outputed echo result in to extra .bat file and started the file. Is there i way to reprogram my code that it will send these outpust in to single one line command?

```
echo off
SET mypath=%~dp0

::THIS STARTS PROGRAM 
(
echo | set /p="""
echo | set /p="C:\Program Files (x86)\Scm Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe" -s -i "
)>seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat

::THIS SEARCHERS FOR PGM FILES AND ADDS PATH OF EACH FILE TO THE LINE
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *.pgm /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
set "file=%%~A"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo | set /p=""" 
echo | set /p="%mypath:~0,-1%\!file:~2!" 
echo | set /p="" " 
)>>seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat


::THIS ADDS SOME EXTRA FILE PATH TO THE LINE OF TOOL FILE, THAT IS NEEDED 
(
echo | set /p=-t "Tlgx\def.tlgx" -m 5
)>>seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat

seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat
```

This code will output file *seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat*  exactly in this format

```
"C:\XConverter.exe" -s -i "C:\a.pgm" "C:\abc\b.pgm" -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5
```

Anyone knows how to reprogram this to send that output to console in single line without creating extra file to store that code?

Edited:

What i need is having *START_CONVERTING.BAT* file that will send to console one command :

```
"C:\XConverter.exe" -s -i "C:\a.pgm" "C:\abc\b.pgm" -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5
```

but *"C:\a.pgm" "C:\abc\b.pgm"* are the search results of all .pgm files in that folder and child folders. So i will copy this *START_CONVERTING.BAT* anywehere where i store .pgm files. (some of them are in folders and those folders in other folders) so i will just copy *STAR_CONVERTING.BAT* in major folder that will thake care of all files with all files in child folders.
I will just click *START_CONVERTING.BAT* and it will convert those .pgm files. (without creating creating any other output to any other .bat file.

---

SOLVED (code)

```
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

PushD "%~dp0"
Set "XC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Scm Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe"
Set "TOOLFILE=Tlgx\def.tlgx"
Set "Files="

:: Concatenate all files in one string
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /S *.pgm') do set Files=!Files! "%%~A"

:: command, command line length may be an issue
"%XC%" -s -i%Files% -t "%TOOLFILE%" -m 5
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow what you want. Perhaps you should describe what you actually need rather than just asking for a solution for your proposed way of the implementation...

Comment: i made edit to explain more, thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right this might work

```
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

PushD "%~dp0"
Set "XC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Scm Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe"
Set "Files="

:: Concatenate all files in one string
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /S *.pgm') do set Files=!Files! "%%~A"

:: store command in batch file, command line length may be an issue
>"seznam_konvertovanych_suboru.bat" Echo "%XC%" -s -i %Files% -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5
```

Comment: this would work ! but area for searched files is empty i used last line only like this "%XC%" -s -i %Files% -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5 this is what i acctualy want. no extra files

Comment: the result was this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Scm Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe" -s -i  -t "tool.tlgx" -m 5   list of files is missing

Comment: there was many .pgm files , looks like %Files% variable is empty

Comment: There was an asterisk missing, please try again

Answer (score 0):

try with that batch

Xconverter is for xxl to PGMX

1 set all path for converter

2 creat to do list of xxl files on desktop on this exemple or desktop sub folder!

3 Masetro can't be install as Office PC you must run it on CN PC!

```
@echo OFF
COLOR F1
TITLE "Convertor XXL to PGMX"
echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo º      Converteur Xconverter         º
echo ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
echo.
echo "Stop command with Ctrl+C"
echo.
Echo "Path SET"
TIMEOUT /t 5 >nul
Set todo="%userprofile%\desktop\todo.txt"
Set def="%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Scm Group\Maestro\Tlgx\def.tlgx"
Set Compil="%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Scm Group\Maestro\Xconverter.exe"
Set desktop="%userprofile%\desktop"


echo "To do list of *.XXL files"
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
cd %userprofile%\desktop
dir /a /b /o /s *.xxl > %todo%


echo "Files convert command"
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%todo%) do %Compil% ^ -s -m 4 ^
-i "%%a" ^
-t %def%


echo "Rapport files"
Timeout /T 10 >nul
cd %desktop%
dir /a /b /o /s *.pgmx > Rapport.txt


Echo "Delete to do list"
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
DEL %todo% /F /S /Q >nul
```

But haven't go detail of Convesion style -m X

if you can replie me detail of -m number it was great!

All the best, and hope this is helpful

D-Alexandre V.